# Yii2 masked input

Tags: php, yii2

Использую [masked input yii2](http://demos.krajee.com/masked-input), поставил вот такое правило:

```
'mask' => '+7(999)999-99-99',
```

и столкнулся с проблемой, к примеру я наберу три символа, уберу фокус с инпута, а значение удалялось, мне нужно как то проверять что пользователь ввел все символы до конца, пытаюсь чрез jquery проверить количество символов, постоянно выдает 16 в независимости сколько там символов.
может кто то сталкивался?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всем спасибо, сам нашел ответ на свой вопрос, если кому то понадобится, вот код

```
<?php
    echo MaskedInput::widget([
        'name' => 'tel',
        'mask' => '+7(999)999-99-99',
        'options'=>[
            'class'=>'form-control tel_input',
        ],
        'clientOptions'=>[
            'clearIncomplete'=>true
        ]
    ]);
?>
```

опция `clearIncomplete` удаляет значение инпута при потере фокуса при условии, что инпут заполнен не полностью